# Client Authentication with Azure KeyVault Secret: PFX -> CERT

Tags: certificate, client, azure-keyvault

1. PFX is uploaded to AzureKeyVault and it is fetched with GetSecretAsync azure call successfully.
2. Import the cert from pfx. now this certificate is used for client authentication.

Question:
In this case, the private key is not available in the machine then how does the client authentication work ?

for reference Code to Fetch the pfx and import to certificate:

```
secretBundle = await kvClientProvider.GetSecretAsync(secretUri, timeoutCancellation.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
if (0 == string.CompareOrdinal(secretBundle.ContentType, 
  CertificateContentType.Pfx))
 { 
    var exportedCertCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
    exportedCertCollection.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(secretBundle.Value));
    var cert = exportedCertCollection.Cast<X509Certificate2>().Single(sc => sc.HasPrivateKey);    
    return cert;
  }
```

Comment: When the PFX is uploaded to the Vault as a secret, does it have the private key? When you say 'private key is not available' in the machine, is this because of the key vault?

Comment: If the code here works, then it found a cert for which `HasPrivateKey` was true.  The PFX format is usually only used when transporting a private key along with a certificate.  So I'm not really sure what the question is?